# Automatically hiding or unhiding rows based on value through VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

If any cells from A8 to A50 are blank, i.e. the formula there returns "", I want only respective row(s) to get hidden automatically, and as soon as any other value is placed as a result of calculation through formula, I want respective rows to be unhidden.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use something like the _change event on the worksheet. Bear in mind this event is only fired if a change has been caused by user action.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim ir As Integer
    Dim colA As Range
    Set colA = Me.Cells(1).EntireColumn
    
    For ir = 8 To 50
        Me.Rows(ir).Hidden = colA.Cells(ir).Value = ""
    Next ir
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks John, works very well but as you mentioned, does not update due to change in underlying data (i.e. update due to formula recalculation). Is there any way to make it run automatically whenever values in cell A8 to A50 change due to formula recalculation.. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Generally, if your cells contain formulas, you can use the `Calculate` event. You can also use the `Change` event for cells that change the value of your cells through formulas. In general, one need to know more about what these formulas are, what they depend on, and how often they change.

Comment: Yes `_Calculate` would be a better event to use. If auto updates happen frequently then `_Calculate` gets fired frequently, so consider optimising the code - e.g. perhaps to update hidden status every 5 seconds instead of on every call.